# Issues implementing a custom button https://cssbuttoncreator.com/ into my basic site

Tags: html, css, button

I have been trying with no success to add a custom button, you create in this site. I have made sure my class is called the same thing in html as the code in css that has been provided BUT nothing happens. I have tried deleting all the different webkits and building it out line by line. The strange thing is when I can get it to work it basically creates the button I do want but with portions of the box on different lines.

```css
.button {
  background: #11CDD4;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #11CDD4, #11999E);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #11CDD4, #11999E);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #11CDD4, #11999E);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #11CDD4, #11999E);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #11CDD4, #11999E);
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 100;
  padding: 40px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 20px 0px #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 20px 0px #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 20px 0px #000000;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 20px #000000;
  border: solid #337FED 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}

.button:hover {
  border: solid #337FED 1px;
  background: #30ECDB;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #30ECDB, #2BC4AD);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #30ECDB, #2BC4AD);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #30ECDB, #2BC4AD);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #30ECDB, #2BC4AD);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #30ECDB, #2BC4AD);
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-me">
  <h2>Get In Touch</h2>
  <h3>If you are interested in collaborating on a project</h3>
  <p class="contact-me-skill"> To be updated.</p>
  <a class="button" href="mailto:myemail@gmail.com">Contact Me</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Voting to close because the problem is caused by a typo. Your start and end tags don't make. Use a validator: https://validator.nu/

Comment: can you please share where the typo is as I clearly cant see it.

Comment: The validator I pointed you at will identify it, as will looking at where the indentation of you code goes weird.

Answer (score 0):

I built [cssbuttoncreator.com](https://cssbuttoncreator.com). Thank you for using my app.

Your issues are as follows:

1. You don't have a closing  tag, instead you have placed a closing  tag.
2. There's an extra closing  tag when there's just one div in the code.